# converting C or C++ to java

Tags: java, c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert .c to .java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473754/convert-c-to-java)

Is there any online free tool for C/C++ to Java?

I searched on the internet but couldnt find a converter C/C++ to Java. In adddition, how can I use header files in converting process to Java.

Comment: You couldn't have searched very hard. The [second hit](http://download.cnet.com/C-To-Java-Converter/3000-2213_4-10080009.html) on my default search engine turned up trumps for C. But *why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: before I post this question I searched and didnt find this question , Trevor

Answer (score 5):

If the code cannot be easily understood, your best option may be to use [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html)  This allows you to call C code from Java without altering it.  You are likely to need to write come bridge code to copy data from the Java world to the C world, but you shouldn't need to change the original C itself.

---

It is hard to be specific with such a broad question.  What you can do is:

- Turn headers into interfaces and classes.
- Turn source class into java files.
- Use the same object a method names where possible.
- Use java's signed values where you currently have unsigned, with work arounds (sometimes none are required)

Comment: as I wrote to Roi, and also I have a homework , I have to make programme and I used these code that is given from my university teacher, in my homework.

Comment: If you code cannot be realistically understood, a computer is going to find it harder to understand.  You best option may be to use JNI.

Answer (score 4):

A tool like that would be extremely large and bloated. The best way to convert C/C++ to Java is by hand.

Comment: I have codes C/C++ and these are very long to understand and also I think it takes long time to convert by hand ://

Comment: If the code you're starting from is hard to understand, I'm pretty sure the resulting code will most likely be harder to understand and maybe even unmaintainable. I don't think there's an easy way out.