# C to Java (binary numbers programm)

Tags: java, c, translate

I made this program on C,and I have no idea of Java (new-yοung developer).Can you help me to "translate" it on Java?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<graphics.h>
void printbin(int num)
{
   int binnum;
   binnum=num%2;
   num=num/2;
   if (num!=0) printbin(num);
   printf("%d",binnum);
   return;
   system("pause");
}

int main(void)
{
   int posnumber,binnum;
   printf("Give a number : ");
   scanf("%d",&posnumber);   
   printbin(posnumber);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO is no code-translation service, sorry. VTC.

Comment: *   #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<graphics.h>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: ok guys..you are professional,but i'm not...it's not for a project of my scholl,it's just for fun...i wanna make it only for..if you can help me,comment...if you wanna just "make some fun" with an idiot that he dont know nothig of developing,couse you are gods,dont make comments @SouravGhosh

Comment: Simply try some online C to Java converter.

Comment: thnx @Igor ...so simple guys!

Comment: Please learn how to format your SO questions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473754/convert-c-to-java for some ideas of online tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn from this code, hope this can help you:

```
//here is comments in java
package help;

import java.util.Scanner;
//this is the way how you can all the libraries in java so
/*
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<graphics.h>
*/    

//here name of your class
public class Help {

    //here name of your methode
    public static void printbin(int num) {
        int binnum;
        binnum = num % 2;
        num = num / 2;
        if (num != 0) {
            printbin(num);
        }
        System.out.println(binnum);
    }

    //here is the main methode in java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int posnumber, binnum;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give a number : ");
        posnumber = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(posnumber);
    }
}
```

Good luck, and good start with java :)

Comment: thnx so much @mrly

Comment: you are welcome :)

Comment: i'll accept it in 6 mnts..thnx again!

Comment: You can check my edit @MarcJackob, i explain more my code good luck :)